# Router cannot find route when sending with parameter

Tags: c#, routes, blazor

I am trying to navigate to a `page` using a parameter , and somehow it seems not to work.
I get the error:

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) Error: System.InvalidOperationException: 'Router' cannot find any component with a route for '/home/+HhbuYzG1j5j/lzjL2gUUYdA5HgM0KYVTx55NYBuYLkYyMOImyVT8627J1iRAkCxjY2ZOAtoA/PuL2dePKX8+qSngAsymb6k010UIk8IG+p7/SlX2PTKEtyVVUXWqgstdmaIn95MXyV0w1XEHYXHm3rv1L5CwIicFtg8b8Vpkng='.
  at Microsoft.JSInterop.DotNetDispatcher.InvokeSynchronously (:8300/System.String assemblyName, System.String methodIdentifier, System.Object targetInstance, System.String argsJson) <0x2a4a160 + 0x001bc> in <af36ed9192be4a95b907125ccf0c1e59>:0 
  at Microsoft.JSInterop.DotNetDispatcher.BeginInvoke (:8300/System.String callId, System.String assemblyName, System.String methodIdentifier, System.Int64 dotNetObjectId, System.String argsJson) <0x2a49d08 + 0x00088> in <af36ed9192be4a95b907125ccf0c1e59>:0 
    at endInvokeDotNetFromJS (blazor.webassembly.js:1)
```

**Sender**

```
@page "/"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services;
@inherits AuthBase

<input type="text" bind="@Username" />
<button type="button" onclick="@AuthAsync">Authenticate</button>
```

**Sender Logic**

```
 public class AuthBase : BlazorComponent {
        [Inject]
        protected IUriHelper uriHelper { get; set; }
        [Inject]
        protected AuthService authService { get; set; }


        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string url = "/home";

        public async Task AuthAsync() {
            var ticket = await this.authService.AuthenticateAsync(Username);
            if (ticket.Value == string.Empty) {
                Console.WriteLine("Ticket invalid,retry !");
                return;
            }
            var urlToSend = url + "/" + ticket.Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Sending to:" + urlToSend); 
            uriHelper.NavigateTo(urlToSend);
        }
    }
```

**Receiver**

```
@page "/home/{Ticket}"
@inherits HomeBase
```

**Receiver Logic**

```
 public class HomeBase:BlazorComponent {

    [Parameter]
    private string Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

I do not understand the url that i am expecting to get called is `/home/[ticketvalue]` and it is correct as you can see from the error.

Why does it not work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your `Ticket` value contains slashes `/`

Comment: I solved it using `Uri.EscapeDataString`. Thanks alot , i totally missed that.